# react-native-reanimated v3 entering animations flicker inside SafeAreaView

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

After I updated my app from reanimated v2 to v3 I'm experiencing various issues with animations. Specifically, the animations lag significantly the first time they are executed. Subsequent executions seem to work fine.

I have uploaded videos to show the problem.

- https://res.cloudinary.com/dynsmaeo3/video/upload/ac_none,e_volume:-100/v1689971871/SPOTLIVE-STATIC/2_-_SD_480p_mjausq.mov
- https://res.cloudinary.com/dynsmaeo3/video/upload/ac_none/v1689971822/SPOTLIVE-STATIC/stackoveflow_-_SD_480p_fr1zlg.mov

I created a repo to show the issue with a fresh install of expo in bare workflow: https://github.com/NiccoloCase/reanimated-bug-test

Answer (score 0):

for single animated, I am using [Moti library](https://moti.fyi/), it's easy, less code, easy control, more type select...